# Barplot make labels horizontal

Tags: r

I know this must be very basic, but this command:

```
barplot(df$var, horiz = T)
```

Is producing this chart:
[image]

Yes, I've read the documentation of `?barplot` and searched and tried lots of different parameter setting, like `beside`, `names.arg`, etc. but I can't make the y labels text horizontal as I'd assume it would be natural once the chart is horizontal.

I did try as per DaveT:

```
barplot(x$value, horiz = T, las=2)
```

Which now crops the labels text:
[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the "las" option to the function:

```
barplot(x$value, horiz = T, las=2)
```

Rstudio has this helpful cheat sheet posted on their website: https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/how-big-is-your-graph.pdf

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. las option is not in the documentation, but it turns the labels horizontally. Pls see my edited question.

Comment: It is in the documentation but hidden under the `par` function.  `par` has many options to adjust the text from the graphics package.

Comment: LOL, thanks, I'm trying to learn all the tricks. Any idea why it is cropping the text?

Comment: Yes, the margins aren't large enough.  See `?par` and you'll need to adjust either the "mai" or "mar" options. (I forget which one without testing)

Answer (score 1):

```
par(mar=c(5,8,4,2) + 0.1) # Doubles left margin.
[draw your plot]
par(mar=c(5,4,4,2) + 0.1) # Restore default
```

If 8 is still too small, try a larger value.
See ?par for details.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18103699/keith)'s answer, you can use a function such as

```
horizontal.plot <- function(pl) {
  par(mar=c(5,8,4,2) + 0.1) # Doubles left margin.
  pl
  par(mar=c(5,4,4,2) + 0.1) # Restore default
}
```

and call it like

```
horizontal.plot(barplot(mydata, hor=TRUE, las=2))
```